# How to use local composer packages in Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, install.packages

I'm trying to use local composer package in Laravel (8.0) - based on
[How to develop a simple Laravel package locally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr8Zc2Zkcjg&ab_channel=AndrewSchmelyun)

I'm using [simonschaufi/laravel-dkim](https://github.com/simonschaufi/laravel-dkim/pull/2)

1. Local copy of package is located in directory:`/packages/simonschaufi/laravel-dkim`
2. My composer file:

```
"repositories": {
     "laravel-dkim": {
         "type": "path",
         "url": "/packages/simonschaufi/laravel-dkim",
         "options": {
             "symlink": true
         }
     }
 },
 "require": {      
     "simonschaufi/laravel-dkim": "@dev"
 },
 "config": {
     "preferred-install": "source",
     "sort-packages": true,
     "optimize-autoloader": true
 },
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "prefer-stable": true
```

Unfortunately, after `composer update` still get original package (instead the local one)

**Do You know what is wrong ????**

Comment: Can you show the top part of your `composer.json`? Did you put `"laravel-dkin: {...}"` in an array of `"repositories"` because I don't see the closing `]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the repositories key to:

```
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/packages/simonschaufi/laravel-dkim"
        }
    ],
```

Other potential problem could be the require:

```
"require": {      
        "simonschaufi/laravel-dkim": "dev-master"
    },
```

Also the require seems a little small? Do you have a duplicate key? Also double check the local path to the package.

Answer (score 1):

Based on help from [Simon Schaufelberger](https://github.com/simonschaufi/laravel-dkim/pull/2):

> the problem was because I used old version of Composer (1.8.4).
> After composer update (to 1.10.13) local package was installed correctly :)

The correct code in composer file is:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./packages/*"
        }
    ],
```

Files should be in directory `/packages/laravel-dkim`